# select rows based on a combination of strings without order in strings

Tags: pandas

If I have the following code:

```
df_ = df_[df_['summary'].str.contains('slow delivery', na=False)]
df_ = df_['summary']
print(df_)
```

And the following list:

```
df_ = ['May be great product, but slow delivery is annoying',
'May be great product, but slow delivery is annoying',
'slow delivery',
'Great product, slow delivery',
'smewhat slow delivery but accurate and wellpackeged. thank you!']
```

But I want to select all the items in the list that contain a combination of slow and delivery, instead of 'slow delivery'.

How does the above need to be adjusted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.str.contains('slow') & .str.contains('delivery')`?

Comment: That will select rows that contain either of slow, or delivery, but not slow & delivery

Comment: *Edited my comment as you were typing that~

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide the full code, as you would do it? To make sure that I do not make any errors when adjusting. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well just make separate masks for both words in this case. If you have a longer list of words, there are better solutions.

```
df_ = df_[df_['summary'].str.contains('slow') & df_['summary'].str.contains('delivery')]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! What do you mean exactly by masks?

Comment: You're making me question everything this morning :') (That's not a bad thing btw). When I say `mask` here, I guess what I really mean is a `boolean vector`. I've seen them referred to as masks before, but now I'm not certain. [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=mask#boolean-indexing)